# Splitting a string by colon

Tags: arrays, bash, unix

I am trying to split the string by ':' and store it in an array, so something that looks like a:b:c:d:x:y:z will be stored in an array which holds, a, b, c, d, x, y, z as elements.

What I have written is

```
IFS = ':' read - r -a ARR <<< "$INFO"
```

where INFO is a string which is being read in from a file containing multiple strings in the aforementioned format.

I get an error saying "IFS: command not found".

I am reading them in this way:

```
while read INFO
```

Lastly when I try to assign the first element in the array to a variable, I am getting an error:

```
export NAME = $INFO[0]
```

the two errors I get here are `export: '=' not a valid identifier` and `export: '[0]: not a valid identifier`

I am relatively a newcomer to bash.

Comment: The basic problem here is that you aren't allowed to put spaces around `=`.

Comment: That said, a note -- `export` isn't part of a regular assignment; it's what you use when you want to make a variable available to *subprocesses*. There's only a limited amount of space available for variables exposed to the process tree in that way, so it shouldn't be used unless you know you need to.

Comment: (also, it's the same space used for command lines, so the more/larger environment variables you have, the shorter your command lines are allowed to be).

Comment: Consider using http://shellcheck.net/ for static checking -- it doesn't catch everything, but it's a good start.

Answer (score 3):

The basic problem here is that your code contains spaces in places where they aren't allowed. For instance, the following is perfectly fine syntax (though it fails to comply with [POSIX conventions on variable naming](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html), which advises lowercase characters be used for application-defined names):

```
info_string='a:b:c:d:x:y:z'
IFS=: read -r -a info_array <<< "$info_string"
```

Similarly, on a dereference, you need curly braces, and (again) can't put spaces around the `=`:

```
name=${info_array[0]}
```

Comment: Understood. I am most comfortable coding in Java and we are told to make our code to "look nice" so I am used to the spacing. Removing the spacing seems to have solved the issue.

Comment: I interpret POSIX's recommendation more weakly than saying *"applications should only use lower case variables"*. I interpret it as saying *"applications should refrain from using variables solely consisting of upper case variables which are reserved, but applications are at liberty to use mixed case"*. I would be interested in your interpretation if you have a moment please.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I agree with you -- mixed case is fine so long as at least one lower-case character is present (which suffices to disambiguate from the all-uppercase namespace). I did specify "be used", vs "be *exclusively* used". :)

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
s=a:b:c:d #sample string
IFS=:
a=( $s ) #array
printf "'%s' " "${a[@]}" #prints 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd'
```

The syntax to get the n-th item in an array is

```
${array_name[$index]}
```

(The curlies are required), so you need `export NAME="${INFO[0]}"` (assignments normally don't need to be quoted, however with `export`, `declare`, `local`, and similar, it's better to quote).

https://www.lukeshu.com/blog/bash-arrays.html is a good tutorial on how bash arrays work.

Comment: This seems to work. However in order to test it to see if I can get the first element I have done NAME=$INFO[0]. When I echo name, I am just getting [0]. Any reason you could think this is happening?

Comment: @TejaMagapu, as the answer here says, the curly braces are required.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sorry I had commented after you commented on with the curly braces. Thank you.

Comment: Try to avoid "saving" the old value of `IFS`, as what is shown here doesn't distinguish between `IFS` being unset and `IFS` having a null value.

Comment: @chepner Is null `IFS` ever needed? Can't users simply use `IFS=' '`?

Comment: The fact remains, an unset `IFS` is treated differently than `IFS=' '`, and that difference should be respected.